# Preposition before noun phrases

Tags: grammar

I have asked the same question in ELL stackexchange, but unfortunately haven't received enough answer/comment. The one answer I got is not satisfactory. So that's the reason I am asking it here again. [Link to ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/52831/preposition-before-noun-phrases).

---

I have seen in some cases prepositions are omitted before some noun phrases. And it's explained that those phrases are actually an adverb phrases. But I know a simple thing. If the head of the phrase is a noun, it's a noun phrase. If the head of the phrase is an adverb it is an adverb phrase.

For example -

> 1. Look **both ways** before crossing the road. [**both ways** is a noun phrase, where the head is **ways**, but still there is no preposition.]
> 2. He approached me *in* **a friendly way**. [**a friendly way** is a noun phrase, where the head is **way**, but as expected unlike sentence #1 it's preceded by the preposition **in**. And I have never seen this phrase is used without a preposition. I believe dropping the preposition is wrong, according to the grammar.]
> 3. She made a pickle **a different way** from her mother. [**a different way** is a noun phrase, where the head is **way**, but strangely there is no preposition before it. But I have seen examples of **a different way** used both with prepositions and without prepositions. I think the preposition here is optional.]

Now from these example sentences I have tried to demonstrate my problem/confusing area. My question is -

**1.** When a noun phrase is used as an adverb phrase?

**2.** When before a noun phrase the placement of preposition is obligatory (like sentence #2)? And where it's optional (like sentence #3)? And where placing the preposition is wrong (like sentence #1)?

Comment: When we call a phrase "a noun phrase" are we saying anything at all about its role in a sentence? No need to answer in haste.

Comment: @TimRomano True, no we don't.

Answer (score 2):

1# *Look both ways*. Commands telling someone *where* to look with *way* typically do not need a preposition: *look my way, look this way, look the other way*.

Conversely, (the much less likely) command telling someone *which looking method to use* can, but does not need to, have the preposition. So, *look in both ways* could mean something like: *Look first with your left eye closed and then with both eyes half open*. The preposition is optional here (in!) the same way that it is in example 3.

2# *He approached me in a friendly way*. In this case, the phrase *in an [adjective] way* means *in an [adjective] manner*. For example, *in a suspicious way, in a hesitant way, in a confident way*. It seems that the *in* is not optional when *way* has this sense.

3# *She made a pickle a different way*. Here *way* is synonymous with *method*. And it appears that the *in* is optional in such contexts. Omitting the preposition when *way* means *method* renders the language more informal. This is what Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p606) says:

> In an informal style, we usually drop the preposition *in* before *way*:
>
> - You're doing it (in) the wrong way.
> - Do it (in) any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster has shown than my answer is probably wrong. It is kept here for reference as follows:

I believe that yours may be a case of the rather advanced rule, cited by Orwell, that one can sometimes omit a conjunction or preposition for euphonic reasons if the meaning remains clear. For example, in "I think I can do it," *to think* is a transitive verb which wants an object, introduced by the conjunction *that*, as in "I think that I can do it." I usually prefer not to omit such words, but Orwell and *The Wall Street Journal* both disagree with me, and they are better writers than I am.

Your point regarding the adverbial phrase is well taken and well explained, and I am not sure that a better answer than mine is not possible, but if my answer is right, then in your sentence, the preposition *in* is implied.

Comment: Thanks. See in sentence #2 it's obligatory to have a preposition, but in sentence #3 it's optional. And in sentence #1 it's obligatory not to have any preposition there. Why, then?

Comment: That is a good question. I don't know.

Comment: I fail to see any logic in the distinction, but idiomatically somehow, the distinction persists. Excellent point.

Answer (score 0):

At 1,

*Look **both ways** = Look **in both directions***

Thus, the preposition is there, implied by the meaning - which you have to know :-)

In 2 and 3, "in" is normally required, e.g. look here at the results at Google Books (do NOT use vanilla Google, it is full of uneducated or of non-native samples) for the core part of your example at 3

[**"a different way from her"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22inside%20of%20the%20window%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a%20different%20way%20from%20her%22&tbm=bks&start=0)

**Practically all the contexts use an "in" in front of the expression.** If an "in" is missing, that is rare and accidental, and not critical in informal speech.

Further,

At COCA [**CORPUS OF CONTEMPORARY AMERICAN ENGLISH**](https://www.english-corpora.org)

there are 25 samples for:

"a different way from"

All of them except one use "in" in front of them. The one not using "in" is coming from an American Indian/Native, who obviously **uses his own English, which is non-standard**:

> Date  2001 (Fall) Publication information     Fall2001, Vol. 25 Issue 4,
> p579, 25p, 3bw Title  Francis LaFlesche and the World of Letters.
> Author    Smith, Sherry L. Source     American Indian Quarterly
>
> Expanded context:
>
> despite change, Native people are asserting ownership over knowledge
> of their cultural history. # Haines informed me that he " understands
> how important salmon has always been to Ahousaht people, but that he
> also understands that whaling was extremely significant to the
> culture, and that's pretty much gone, the way of the dodo. " James
> Curtis, on the other hand, explained that fishing, preparing,
> distributing, and consuming wild seafoods is not a fashion but a way
> of being that recreates the past while envisioning the future: # Our
> people **use fish a different way from white people**. He Carl Haines
> may eat it, but it's like, it's kind of a trophy thing. I don't like
> to put it that way, but it's like this is one that I caught.

**Other than that, all the examples, even in SPOKEN, such as this one, are using the "in"**:

> Date  1999 (19990221) Title   THE COMEBACK; IF HILLARY CLINTON'S CLIMB
> IN POPULARITY POLLS WILL ENSURE HER FUTURE Source     CBS_SunMorn
>
> But compare Hillary Clinton to other first ladies, say
> Barbara Bush, who was polling 20:1 positive even when her husband was
> losing to Bill Clinton in 1992. KATHLEEN-FRANKOVIC: It's fair to say
> that she was, in fact, being judged by different standards than other
> first ladies, but part of that is probably because **she was acting as
> first lady in a different way from other first ladies**. TEICHNER:
> (Voiceover) Kathleen Frankovic heads the CBS News polling unit.

Further, at the
[The British National Corpus (BNC)](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/)

try to look up for

**a different way from**

[no quotes]

Please tell me how many of the results are using "in." I'd say all.

**Thus, all three Google Books, COCA and BNC statistics contradict your assumption that "in" is optional at 3.**

Comment: That in sentence #3 it's optional I know. But see it's not optional in sentence #2 :O Yes I know it's safe to use a preposition there, but I am concerned when it's right if it's omitted.

Comment: I did not say it's optional in 3. It's not. It's  an accidental occurrence, which is tolerated, see thb's answer.

Comment: I beg to differ. I have copied that sentence probably from Cambridge dictionary. Chances are that there is no accidental occurrence.

Comment: Why don't you drill down in the stats from Google Books in my link, to try to find missing "in"s? You  won't find many, if one:-)

Comment: Yes I have already visited your link and found what you meant :-)

Comment: I've added the BNC results. Same.