# Is it Ok to omit 'IN' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I found this phrase in the *Clean Code* book:

> Pragmatic Dave Thomas and Andy Hunt said this a different way.

Is this phrase correct? From what I know, one should write:

> Pragmatic Dave Thomas and Andy Hunt said this **in** a different way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preposition before noun phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237680/preposition-before-noun-phrases) See Shoe's answer: 'This is what Swan in 'Practical English Usage' (p606) says: ...... In an informal style, we usually drop the preposition _in_ before _way_: ...... _You're doing it (in) the wrong way._ ...... _Do it (in) any way you like._

Comment: There is nothing wrong with omitting *in* in that sentence. It happens all the time.

Answer (score -1):

I think the prase *isn't* correct.
Same as you, i think that "in" should be in the sentance, and in the orginal phrase it is not.